# Can't write into a text file with for loop in c

Tags: c, for-loop, malloc, c-strings, writefile

I have an issue with writing strings into a txt file. My lines get overwritten every time. I use
`gcc -Wall -o filename filename.c` to compile and `./filename 10 Berlin cat resultat.txt` to execute. 
The txt file always has just one line (the last one) how can I save all the records.

I have a CSV file with city names and a number of residents, I need to filter for the City name and a minimum of residents.

What I tried so far:

```
.....
void write_file(char *result[], int len) {
   FILE *fp = fopen("resultat.txt", "w");
   if (fp == NULL){
       perror("resultat.txt");
       exit(1);
   }
   for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
       fprintf(fp, "%s\n", result[i]);
   }
   fclose(fp);
}

int main(int argc,char **argv) {

    int anzahl = atoi(argv[1]);
    char *string_array[100];

    char *erste_zeile;
    erste_zeile = (char *) malloc(1000 * sizeof(char));

    char staedte[MAX_LAENGE_ARR][MAX_LAENGE_STR];
    char laender[MAX_LAENGE_ARR][MAX_LAENGE_STR]; 
    int bewohner[MAX_LAENGE_ARR];

    int len = read_file("staedte.csv", staedte, laender, bewohner);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i){
         if (strcmp(argv[2],laender[i])==0 && anzahl < bewohner[i]){
            snprintf(erste_zeile, 100,"Die Stadt %s hat %d Einwohner\n",staedte[i],bewohner[i]);

            string_array[0] = erste_zeile;
            // counter++;
            write_file(string_array,1);
        }
    }

    free(erste_zeile);
    return 0;
}
```

Using the `write_file()` function outside of the for loop gives me `null` values. If anybody has an idea how to optimize the code please leave a comment or answer.

Comment: it is better to open the file only onse before the loop and close it after the loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each time you use `FILE *fp = fopen("resultat.txt", "w");` what this does is delete the existing file and create a blank file for writing. What you're looking for is `FILE *fp = fopen("resultat.txt", "a"); //a not w!`. This will open the existing file and append content. If a file does not exist, one will be created. See [this reference](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fopen.htm).

> **"w" -** 
>   Creates an empty file for writing. If a file with the same name already exists, its content is erased and the file is considered as a new empty file.
>
> **"a" -**
>   Appends to a file. Writing operations, append data at the end of the file. The file is created if it does not exist.

Also heed @Serge's advice about not opening the file for each record. Just open it once in the `main` and use the file handle to write to it. To make your current code work, you can do this:

```
void write_file(char *result[], int len) {
   FILE *fp = fopen("resultat.txt", "a");//open for append
   if (fp == NULL){
       perror("resultat.txt");
       exit(1);
   }
   for (int i=0; i < len; i++) {
       fprintf(fp, "%s\n", result[i]);
   }
   fclose(fp);
}
```